# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"name\" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying\n?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I want to insert new data to postgres database in spring using java but when I run project I am getting following exception

```
"timestamp": "2023-08-08T07:25:26.678+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO movie(name, release_date)\nVALUES (?, ?);\n]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"name\" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying\n  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.\n  Position: 47",
    "path": "/api/v1/movies"
}
```

below my insert movie method

```
@Override
    public int insertMovie(Movie movie) {
        var sql = """
                INSERT INTO movie(name, release_date)
                VALUES (?, ?);
                 """;
        return jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                movie.name(), movie.releaseDate()
        );
    }
```

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake any help and suggestions highly appreciated  I have tried all answers in stackoverflow it did not solve my problem

Comment: Please add your `movie` table's definition

Comment: Error is pretty clear: In your `movie` table, the `name` column is an `integer`, but you are passing a `String` (from `movie.name()`)

Comment: how can I pass correctly

Comment: @Override
    public int insertMovie(Movie movie) {
        var sql = """
            INSERT INTO movie(name, release_date)
            VALUES (?, ?);
             """;
        try {
            int name = Integer.parseInt(movie.name());
            return jdbcTemplate.update(
                    sql,
                    name, movie.releaseDate()
            );
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Update the movie object with the value null for the name property
            movie.name();
            return -1;
        }
    }

Comment: it is not working @Arnaud can you clearify what do you mean bu movie table definition]

Comment: *int name = Integer.parseInt(movie.name());* How and why is a movie name a number?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Your code says that the movie name is a number and you want to turn it into an `int`. Why is it a number?

Comment: I dont know I am following tutorial if you check above code in the post I am passing exactly

Comment: @Override
    public int insertMovie(Movie movie) {
        var sql = """
                INSERT INTO movie(name, release_date)
                VALUES (?, ?);
                 """;
        return jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                movie.name(), movie.releaseDate() I am not passing any int but I am passing string for name
        );
    }

Comment: *I dont know I am following tutorial* URL please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254843/discussion-between-edgar-and-g00se).

Comment: @g00se Please check this tutorial code https://github.com/amigoscode/jdbc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/amigoscode/movie/MovieDataAccessService.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by updating sql command